# Pronunciation of verbiage and foliage

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

To my ear, the former should be pronounced "vurb-ij" and the latter "fohl-ee-ij" (the endings may vary among "aj", "edge" and "ij").

I occasionally hear people say "vurb-ee-ij" and often hear "fohl-ij".

Are they interchangeable? Regional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Merriam-Webster and my own experience, the three-syllable versions of both words are the "more proper" ones.  While the two-syllable version of *verbiage* is quite common, I rarely hear *foliage* with only two syllables (but this could be regional; see below).  M-W marks two-syllable pronunciations of *foliage* as "questionable".  Here is an explanatory excerpt from M-W:

> The disyllabic pronunciation \ˈfō-lij\
>   is very common. Some commentators
>   insist that foliage requires a
>   trisyllabic pronunciation because of
>   its spelling, but words of a similar
>   pattern such as carriage and marriage
>   do not fall under their prescription.
>   The pronunciation \ˈfȯi-lij\ is
>   disapproved because it suggests the
>   transposition of the l and i in the
>   spelling. It is not as common as
>   \ˈfō-lij\ and may be associated with
>   the nonstandard spelling foilage.

Comment: George W. Bush pronounces it \ˈfō-lij\.

Answer (score 3):

In England, as often as I've heard those words used, they were always ee-aj or ee-ej (like age)at the end.
So Verb-ee-aj or verb-ee-ej.
Fol-ee-aj or fol-ee-ej.

Comment: Seconded; I’d never heard the 2-syllable version of *foliage* before I moved to the US.

Answer (score 0):

I'd never heard foliage pronounced without the "i" until I moved from New Zealand to Australia. In Australia you never hear it with the "i" unless my wife and I are the ones saying it!